# How to change LabVIEW Control value (in already running VI) via Active X?

Tags: matlab, activex, labview

I am trying set a control value in my VI (which is already running).

I use the following commands:

```
e=actxserver('LabVIEW.Application');
vipath='C:\DATA\Labview\test.vi';
vi=invoke(e,'GetVIReference',vipath); 
% my control parameter is z which is DBL (double precision)
vi.SetControlValue('z',10)
```

Everything seems to work fine ! **I can see the 'z' value change to 10** in VI but actually VI is not reading that value and **VI application is not responding to this value**

The VI is a third party application, which is developed by someone else. Unfortunately, I don't have privilege in this forum to post a picture of it (I need 10 points)

I am trying to control variable "z" from Matlab. The "z"is an input to a .dll file. Note that I can do it by front panel control in VI, but can't using Matlab as described earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ! The control variable 'z' was within a event structure, and it was set to value change of 'z'. So, I just removed it for the time being and it works well.

However, I am not sure how to work with an event structure to control it using Matlab active x

Comment: You should be able to port the following LabVIEW code to Matlab: http://i.imgur.com/C102sbg.png

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code, it's impossible to tell, but here are a couple of guesses:

Are you reading the control using a value change event? This event is only triggered either by a change in the UI or by calling the Value(Signaling) property for the control. I'm not sure if you can access this property from the ActiveX interface, but you can try by getting a reference to the control (although I have no idea how that's done from the ActiveX interface either. Maybe the VI has a method?). If you can't, the best would probably be to change the VI to poll the control. You could also have another loop which will fire the event whenever the control changes, but if you do that, I would suggest you have a separate control just for passing that value.

Another possibility - the value is read from the control's terminal before you modified it and your code uses the value on the wire, not the value from the control.

If that doesn't help, post the code.

Comment: The VI is a third party application, which is developed by someone else. Unfortunately, I don't have privilege in this forum to post a picture of it (I need 10 points)
I am trying to control variable "z" from Matlab. The "z"is an input to a .dll file. Note that I can do it by front panel control in VI, but can't using Matlab as described earlier.